Should the O.P. be allowed to delete a Q&A that is not helpful?
I am not allowed to delete my question, because it "already has answers."
The problem is that the only answer is incomplete and the many comments mix statements by me about what worked and didn't work with statements by others contradicting me.
Either I am a troll and a liar (as some suggested) and my comments could mislead people unfavorably, or they are wrong and their comments could mislead people unfavorably.
Thus, I see no benefit in leaving the argument on the site.

Asking a question is a big deal, asking a question then deleting it after community involvement, is not a positive activity. If the answer is not helpful then downvote it. If you want a better answer [edit] your question and clarify it. The fact you clarified your question with comments is your decision, a decision that resulted in your question being downvoted for not being clear, since you clarified everything in the comment section of an answer. You have been a user for 14 years, you should know, how the community works by now.

Worth pointing out deleting the question would still count against your ability to ask new questions. Removal of that question would only restore 6 reputation points. Any negative results from the question existing is permanent

Nobody suggested you were a troll or a liar. They merely suggested that you might be mistaken about the result of a certain bit of code on certain input. When comments suggest that a question might be clear, you should edit the question to incorporate the feedback - do not try to clarify by responding to the comments. If you reply to the comments, it should be because you don't understand the request.

Instead of saying and emboldening things like "I haven't been able to figure out a regexp with those limitations.  How can that be done?", referring to ideas strewn about the previous paragraph - please try to ask directly: "What regex can I use to match strings which: [list requirements here]?". But please keep in mind that regex questions like this are usually not suitable, because they are effectively requests to write code without a meaningful question behind them: regex is effectively a separate programming language.


Thus, I see no benefit in leaving the argument on the site.

That is right. We should not keep unhelpful comments on the site. As such, you should delete the comments or flag them as 'No longer needed.' There is no need to destroy an entire Q&A just because there are some bad comments which can be purged anyway.
Instead, I would focus on editing the question to resolve the close reason and the additional issues brought up in comments, like by adding sample input text as suggested.
You can additionally clarify/emphasize the parts of the question that you find the solution proposed in the answer to not address.

I see no benefit to anyone for me to delete my comments that accurately describe what I witnessed and leaving those of other that say it didn't happen.

@WGroleau How about leaving none? Just 'accurately' describe what is missed in the question itself, and have all the comments deleted, either by deleting them yourself if they are yours, or flagging them as 'No longer deleted' if they are not, in which case they will be deleted by the moderators shortly.

@WGroleau - You might not have a choice. Over 30 comments were submitted, those comments should have never been submitted, and were flag as “no longer being necessary” by the community.
